# Access EC2 site with port

Tags: amazon-ec2

Hi I have create new site in EC2 with port 8099. Which I can access fine within the server like.

```
http://localhost:8099/Site.html
```

But while trying locally

```
http://00.00.00.00:8099/Site.html //note: I am using IP, no domain name
```

I am getting connection timeout error.

I have also edited 'inbound rule' ie Custome TCP Rule --> TCP --> 8099

What else I need to do to get access? I have this post also in Stackoverflow, not sure which is the best site to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to verify that the Security Group rules applied to this instance allow TCP port 8099 and additionally that your OS firewall is not blocking this traffic.